# Binary Column is translated to null Java type

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I created a domain in JasperRreports Server.  I have a table that stores Binary data. When I use it in my domain I get a the following error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getObjectType for javaType: null
>   returned null

I exported the schema and found the following:

```
<field id="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" />
<field id="FileData" type="null" />
```

As you can see, null is used in the type field.  I tried changing this to java.io.InputStream which is the type that it maps to when I connect to the data source directly and got the same error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getObjectType for javaType:
>   java.io.InputStream returned null at
>   com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.ObjectTypeMapper.getObjectType(ObjectTypeMapper.java:69)

Any reports using that domain fail to run until I remove the Binary column.  When I try to create a Domain report in *iReport*, it can not retrieve the domain fields.  When I try to use the adhoc reporting tool I get the error above.

I am using *SQL Server 2005*, the type of the data is 'image'.  I cast the column to varbinary in my view to see if *JasperReports* would recognize it and I still have the same error.

Has anyone successfully used binary data types in *JasperReports Server* domains?

**Update:**  I configured the bean "jdbcMetaConfiguration"  in applicationContext-semanticLayer.xml to map the binary column to java.io.InputStream and I still get the same error.  The mapping worked, when I view the XML file "null" is replaced with "java;io.InputStream" but I still get IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Nope, it cannot be done. Sorry.

**Original [overly-optimistic] answer**:
The Ad Hoc editor cannot handle images (or other binary data types). It would be nice if it more gracefully ignored them... but it's no surprise that you cannot use them there.

But it should be possible to define the field as some sort of binary (image or array of bytes or just an Object or something like these) and then use it in iReport.

Comment: Normally, iReport allows changing it to java.io.InputStream, but when the domain contains the FileData column, iReport cannot display any tables in the domain.

Comment: My theory is breaking down in light of your results. Have you logged a case with tech support?